# NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT when trying to connect with samba client

Tags: networking, samba, local-network

I am trying to connect to a windows machine in my local network from ubuntu with samba client. To send a message I type :

```
smbclient -M 192.168.1.10
```

But I get

```
Connection to 192.168.1.10 failed. Error NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT
```

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely because the box your trying to do smbclient uses an outdated (and insecure) version of SMB such as SMBv1.

You'll need to edit the smb.conf in your machine and specify the **client min protocol** into **CORE**. You'll also need to specify the **client max protocol** into **SMB3**.

More information here: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html

Steps:
On your host machine:

1. sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
2. Add the following settings under Global Settings:
   client min protocol = CORE 
    client max protocol = SMB3
3. Write (Ctrl + O) and Exit (Ctrl + X) nano text editor.
4. Retry smbclient

[image: smb.conf screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The error code `NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT` may apply to blocked SMB ports on the server or on the firewall, if client and server are on different subnets.

Comment: Or your ISP blocking... which turned out to be my case using Charter Spectrum: https://www.spectrum.net/support/internet/blocked-ports

Answer (score 0):

Going to the Server Manager Application in Windows SQL server and downloading the .NET 3.5 and telnet, the issue resolved.